# Visual Basic Sybase connection issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-connection, sybase

I am developing code in Visual Basic 2010 and connecting to Sybase16 databases hosted on two servers. I am referencing Sybase iAnywhere in my project.
I use the connection string shown below

```
    Public dbIMS As New SAConnection
    dbIMS.ConnectionString="UserID=userid;Password=userpw;DatabaseName=dbname;ServerName=dbname;Host=192.000.000.000;"
    Try
    dbims.open()
    Catch ex as Exception
    strErrMsg=ex.Message.ToString
    End Try
```

I can connect to some databases, but not others. Error message is "Database server not found" All databases are active and the service name and db filename are the same for each database. I can connect to some dbs on each server and as yet have been unable to find anything in common with the successful connections or the failed connections. I am certain the ip address is correct and the db and server names are correct.
I am looking for advice on how to diagnose my problem, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Firewalls blocking the calls?

Comment: No, same route for the ones that i can connect to and the ones I can't

Comment: Can you try giving full host name with domain rather than using IP address

Comment: ANSWER: I added " :0000" they Sybase port number for the database service to the end of the HOST and it works every time now.